# VBA - Delete previously saved values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where I store the values the user selected.
[image]

I have a userform pop-up with a warning saying: "There are previously saved values. Do you want to keep them? If they say yes, all good, but if they say no I need to delete the previously saved values.

This userform appears in the middle of the process (not possible to change), so there will already be new saved values that I need to keep.

[image]

I though of having some index number, for example the first saved values get a 1, the next saved batch get a 2. Then, if I wanted to delete I would just have to delete the older batch. However, I'm not sure how to implement this.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about you clear range where data is stored with Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G37").Clear if you press NO and then write new data, in rows bellow title, but if you press YES, then determine last row in column where data is stored and write data in next row.

Comment: The code I'm using for the "Yes" option is working pretty well, but the problem is that the new data is already written, so if I press "No" and clear, everything will be deleted (including the new data). Hope it makes sense!

Comment: If you know how many rows you pasted at end and last row with data you can calculate how many previous rows should be deleted, then delete them with .clear and that will make blank rows. Then you will have to move data "up", next to title, and then remove duplication in case you did create second set of data. Maybe you can rearrange your algorithm, sounds kinda complex, but can be done as described.

Comment: The thing is I will never know how many new rows of data have been added. Would you possible know how to add an "index"? By index I mean, when a user adds values all those values have a 1 in the next column. The second time they add new values, the index will be 2. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think you are kinda overthinking, before adding new rows, just count old ones, then add new rows, then recount old + new rows, then calculate difference and you get how many rows you added. If you start messing with indexes then you will have to read index when you restart macro, but yes can be done, but you are creating more complex system when it is not necessary probably.

Comment: Oh I see your point! Thank you, I'll follow your suggestion. Much appreciated!